# Which Android devices don't download OBB expansion files directly from the Google Play Store?

Tags: android, apk, apk-expansion-files, mobile-devices

Which criterias define if an Android device is able to directly download an OBB expansion file from the google play store?

Does it depend on hardware and/or Android version?